# Ambiguity in sentence: retrieving a document marked as relevant by pure chance

Tags: ambiguity

There is an ambiguity in the following sentence, since it is not obvious whether by pure chance refers to retrieving a document or to marked as relevant. I want to make it explicit that the document is marked as relevant by pure chance. How can I do that?

we will show that retrieving a document marked as relevant by pure chance is very unlikely.

Comment: ... a document marked by pure chance as relevant ...

Comment: We will show that the likelihood of retrieving a document which was marked  as relevant purely by chance is very low.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"We will show that retrieving a document marked by pure chance as relevant is unlikely."

Or,

"We will show that* it is unlikely that a document marked as relevant by pure chance will be retrieved."

**optional*

Or,

"We will show that is is unlikely to retrieve a document marked by pure chance as relevant."

More clarity is achieved by putting "marked" and "by pure chance" next to each other.